# How do I process a contact for created in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, contact-form

I'm running Angular 7 and I've created a contact for that I plan to connect to firebase to save contact submissions. However, I'd like to be notified when a person fills out the form. What's the "most common" way to handle contact form submissions that will notify me via email when the a form has been submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would look into `Cloud Functions`. Assuming you're saving the contact submission into the database, you could trigger a function to send you an email alerting you of the submission.

There is a good example in the [`firebase/functions-samples`](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/email-confirmation) GitHub repo, which triggering an email when a database record is written to.

--

Alternatively you could make a HTTP Cloud Function which accepts `POST` requests and converts the contact submission into an email to your inbox.

OR instead of a HTTP Endpoint, you could create a [`callable`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) function which is kind of similar but removes some of the HTTP overhead.

Comment: perfect, thanks for the info. Looks like this one of these is the direction I want to go, likely `Cloud Functions`